# Error about arguments of length zero when judge a dataframe is Null in R

Tags: r, if-statement

Hi there I am new to R and I am trying to see if the df is Null, if it is, then assigned "empty" to it but there is an error like this, do you know how to solve it?

```
if(is.na(df)){
  df <- "Empty"}
```

Error in if (is.na(data_si)) { : argument is of length zero

Comment: If you are just looking for  whether df is empty or not ,you can use `if(nrow(df)==0) {print("df is empty")} else {print("df has at least one observation")}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have this data frame

```
df<-data.frame(
  A=c('A1','A2','A3','A4'),
  B=c(1,2,3,NA)
)
print(df)
```

output:

```
   A  B
1 A1  1
2 A2  2
3 A3  3
4 A4 NULL
```

And you want to replace the missing value with the word "Empty". Then, you can do a nested for loop, combined with if statement:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  for(j in 1:length(df)){
    if(is.null(df[i,j])){
      df[i,j]<-'empty'
    }else{
      next
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
 A     B
1 A1     1
2 A2     2
3 A3     3
4 A4 empty
```

The reason for this code is to inspect every single entry inside the data frame, whether they are NA or not. The "i" represents index for rows and the "j" represents index for column. The "next" means we skip the particular entry if it's not NULL (do nothing if it's not NULL)

Another way to do this problem is by using ifelse.
You can search manually for each columns

```
df$A<-ifelse(is.null(df$A),'empty',df$A)
df$B<-ifelse(is.null(df$B),'empty',df$B)
```

or you can also use for loop as well

```
for(i in 1:length(df)){
  df[,i]<-ifelse(is.null(df[,i]),'empty',df[,i])
}
```

Both ways will give you the same results

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, thank you for the code, I am sorry that I didn't describe clearly, so the df itself when printed in the console, the output is "NULL", I want to reassign df to other value not the "NULL"

Comment: then if it's the case, you can replace the is.na() with the is.null() function @YihanBao

Answer (score 0):

Subset the whole dataframe on NA values and replace them:

```
df[is.na(df)] <- "Empty"
df
   A     B
1 A1     1
2 A2     2
3 A3     3
4 A4 Empty
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the code, I am sorry that I didn't describe clearly, so the df itself when printed in the console, the output is "NULL", I want to reassign df to other value such as a string or a number not the "NULL"